# Right set of tactics to use in Z3 to solve these inequalities

Tags: z3

Here x and k are integers
and the formula is:  (50<=x+k Ʌ x+k<51)

Can it get simplified to "x+k=50"

I want the right set of tactics to solve this conjunction of inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

Z3 is not a general purpose symbolic engine to simplify such expressions. Even if you got a good combination of tactics to give you what you need today, the results might change in further releases of the tool. You should look at other systems. Even a symbolic-engine like wolfram-alpha may not produce what you exactly want; but it might give you some alternative forms that might be easier to work with. See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50%3C%3Dx%2Bk+%26%26+x%2Bk%3C51